# Proof that $\sin^{2n + 1}(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n} a_{i} \sin\left(\left(2i + 1\right)x\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

In playing around on wolframalpha, I noticed that $\sin^{2n + 1}(x)$ where $n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$ takes the form:

$$\sin^{2n + 1}(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n} a_{i} \sin\left(\left(2i + 1\right)x\right)$$

Where $a_{i} \in \mathbb{Q}$

Does anyone have any ideas on how one would go about (dis)proving this?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean for the sum to go from $i = 0$ to $i = n-1$?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 - No I believe it is $n - 1$. Do you have example of it not working?

Comment: For $n = 1$, can you write $\sin^3 x = a_1\sin(3x)+a_2\sin(5x)$? If $x = \pi/2$, we get $-a_1+a_2 = 1$. If $x = \pi/4$, we get $\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}a_1-\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}a_2 = \tfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$, i.e. $-a_1+a_2 = -\tfrac{1}{2}$. This is a contradiction. I made a slight mistake earlier. I think the sum should run from $i = 0$ to $i = n$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 - You are indeed correct. Thank you for the comment, I will correct the expression.

Comment: I've also just been able to prove it using 'Proof by Induction' - Too messy to type up on my iPad. Will post up when I get home.

Comment: Yep, all you need for the inductive step is De Moivre's formula.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 - I just used $\sin^{2k + 3}(x) = \sin^2(x)\sin^{2k + 1}(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(1 - \cos(2x)\right)\sin^{2k + 1}(x)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a thought that came to mine on how this could be proven

Employ proof my induction

Step (1) : Prove true for $n = 0 $

$$\sin^{1}(x) = 1\cdot\sin(1\cdot x) = \sum_{i = 0}^{0} a_{i}^{(0)}\sin\left(\left(2i + 1\right)x\right)$$

Hence true.

Step (2) : Inductive Step - Assume true for $n = k$:

$$\sin^{2k + 1}(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{k + 1}a_{i}^{(k)}\sin\left(\left(2i + 1\right)x\right)$$

Step (3) : Prove true for $n = k + 1$. Hence show,

$$\sin^{2(k + 1) + 1}(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{k + 1}a_{i}^{(k + 1)}\sin\left(\left(2i + 1\right)x\right)$$

Now,

\begin{align}
\sin^{2k + 3}(x) &= \sin^{2}\left(x\right)\sin^{2k + 1}(x)  \\
&= \left[\frac{1 - \cos(2x)}{2} \right]\sum_{i = 0}^{k}a_{i}^{(k)}\sin\left(\left(2i + 1\right)x\right) \\
&= \sum_{i = 0}^{k}\frac{a_{i}^{(k)}}{2}\sin\left(\left(2i + 1\right)x\right) - \sum_{i = 0}^{k }\frac{a_{i}^{(k)}}{2}\cos(2x)\sin\left(\left(2i + 1\right)x\right) \\
&= \sum_{i = 0}^{k}\frac{a_{i}^{(k)}}{2}\sin\left(\left(2i + 1\right)x\right) - \sum_{i = 0}^{k}\frac{a_{i}^{(k)}}{4}\left[\sin\left(\left(2i + 3\right)x\right) + \sin\left(\left(2i - 1\right)x\right) \right]
 \\
&= \sum_{i = 0}^{k}\frac{a_{i}^{(k)}}{2}\sin\left(\left(2i + 1\right)x\right) - \sum_{i = 1}^{k + 1}\frac{a_{i-1}^{(k)}}{4}\sin\left(\left(2i + 1\right)x\right) -\sum_{i = -1}^{k - 1}\frac{a_{i + 1}^{(k)}}{4} \sin\left(\left(2i + 1\right)x\right) \\
&=\sum_{i = 1}^{k - 1}\left[\frac{2a_{i}^{(k)} - a_{i - 1}^{(k)} - a_{i+1}^{(k)}}{4}\right]\sin\left(\left(2i + 1\right)x\right) + \left[\frac{3a_{0}^{(k)} - a_{1}^{(k)}}{4} \right]\sin\left(\left(2\cdot0 + 1\right)x\right)\\
&\qquad - \left[\frac{2a_{k}^{(k)} - a_{k - 1}^{(k)}}{4}\right]\sin\left(\left(2k + 1\right)x\right) 
 - \frac{a_{k}^{(k)}}{4}\sin\left(\left(2\left(k + 1\right) + 1\right)x\right) \\
&= \sum_{i = 0}^{k + 1} a_{i + 1}^{(k + 1)} \sin\left(\left(2i + 1\right)x\right)
\end{align}
Where

$$a_{i + 1}^{(k + 1)} = \begin{cases} 
      \frac{3a_{0}^{(k)} - a_{1}^{(k)}}{4} & i = 0\\
      \frac{2a_{i}^{(k)} - a_{i - 1}^{(k)} - a_{i+1}^{(k)}}{4} & 1\leq i\leq k - 1 \\
      \frac{2a_{k}^{(k)} - a_{k - 1}^{(k)}}{4} & i =  k \\
    -\frac{a_{k}^{(k)}}{4} & i = k + 1
\end{cases}$$

As required.